# why value is ambigious if the logical operator syntax is correct

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am receiving below error message in Python after this line of code:
data is the panda data frame and A, B are numbers.

```
if((data.loc[ii]>=A) & (data.loc[ii]<B)):
                labels[ii]=C
```

**Error :The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

I have read everything in the internet it says use & instead of and and | instead of or, I even use the parenthesis to avoid operator precedence rule but I am wondering why I am still getting the above error since I am using correct logical operator ?.

Thanks

Comment: What's the value of the conditional (ie. without the `if`)?

Comment: I just tried for different values and without if, sometimes I get true and sometimes false depending on which elements of data is accessed

Comment: The return of `(...)>=A & (...)<B`is a series. It doesn't make much sense to do `if series`. You have to understand what you're trying to accomplish and then use e.g. `any()` or `item()` at the end to correctly implement the logic. For example, if you wanna know if there is *some case* in which an object is both `>= A` and `< B`, then you do your code `(..).any()`which would return `True`or`False`. Now, if you wanna know if *all* elements in your series are indeed `>=A` or `<B`, then you'd do your code `(...).all()` instead. etc etc

Comment: `numpy` raises this error when a boolean array with more than one element occurs in an `if` context (or other cases that expect a scalar boolean).   In other words, `np.array([True, False, True, True])` is ambiguous.

Comment: @hpaulj None of the answers in other posts were useful for me